# update or convert a date time value in a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a SQLite database with a TEXT column that stores a DateTime value formated like this: '11/08/2019 00:00:00'. I would like to convert the entire column contents to UTC Epoch timestamp local timezone.
Is there an Update SQL string with a DateTime function that I could run using supported SQL syntax to perform this task or should I perhaps just write a quick C# console application to do it?
I have not found any example online or in SO that would do what I need to do in this situation.

Comment: If you change your date string format to one supported by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) then I think so (not really sure what "local timezone" has to do with a Unix epoch time which is utc based...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UPDATE SQL such as :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 
CASE WHEN substr(mycolumn,3,1) = '/' 
    THEN
        strftime('%s',substr(mycolumn,7,4)||'-'||substr(mycolumn,4,2)||'-'||substr(mycolumn,1,2)||' '||substr(mycolumn,12,8))
    ELSE
        mycolumn
    END
;
```

could be used.

## Example

Perhaps consider the following which will convert the column (or not if it has already been converted (or not if it does not match the dd/mm/yyyy format))

- Note the below just checks the 3rd character for **/**, a more rigorous check could be used if desired.

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mycolumn TEXT);
/* Load the testing data */
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
    ('11/08/2019 00:00:00'),
    ('01/08/2019 00:00:00'),
    ('31/01/2019 00:00:00'),
    ('31/01/2019 13:25:33.004') /* test for micro seconds (dropped by utc)*/;
/* display data before conversion */
SELECT * FROM mytable; 
/* Convert the data to unix */
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 
    CASE WHEN substr(mycolumn,3,1) = '/' 
        THEN
            strftime('%s',substr(mycolumn,7,4)||'-'||substr(mycolumn,4,2)||'-'||substr(mycolumn,1,2)||' '||substr(mycolumn,12,8))
        ELSE
            mycolumn
        END
    ;
    /* Display data as is, as formatted localised and as formatted UTC */
SELECT *, datetime(mycolumn,'unixepoch','localtime') AS local, datetime(mycolumn,'unixepoch') AS utc FROM mytable;
```

- Note the above would NOT cater for dates such as 1/1/2019, such dates would need a more complex CASE clause.
- Note that UTC is worldwide coordinated time i.e one value is stored you adjust from UTC according to the time zone

## Results

- Note testing in timezone that is +10 hours

### When first run the results are :-

#### Pre-conversion :-

[image]

#### Post-convserion

[image]

### Rerun (DROP commented out)

#### Pre-conversion (mixed data) :-

[image]

- circled data is already converted

#### Post-conversion :-

[image]